# На странице конфликтуют два dropdown списка, подскажите где ошибка?

Tags: javascript, dropdown

Написал JS код для dropdown списка, один работает хорошо, а со вторым не уживается, подскажите где ошибка? Так как на странице будут много dropdown списков, а хотелось бы что бы работали независимо друг от друга и при этом код JS не раздувался.

```js
/*Функция добавляет/удаляет класс для показа списка.*/
function myFunction() {
    document.querySelector('.dropdown-content').classList.toggle('show');
}


window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        let dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content');

        for (let i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            let openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
};

/* Выбираю конкретный селектор */
document.querySelector('.dropbtn').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

body {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Home</button>

  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div>blog</div>
    <div>About</div>
    <div>Contact</div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Home</button>

  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div>blog</div>
    <div>About</div>
    <div>Contact</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Нужна помощь только на чистом JavaScript!

Comment: Нужно, чтобы каждый элемент получил этот функционал. Сейчас функция работает с первым попавшимся на странице элементом.

Comment: Меняю querySelector на querySelectorAll тогда вообще не работает, или я чего-то не догоняю, подскажите хотя бы с маленьким примером.

Comment: @alex-lenk querySelectorAll возвращает тебе список элементов.

Comment: То есть, мне надо через цикл пройтись? 

for(var i in els){
}

Пожалуйста, приведи хотя бы краткий пример, что можно использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* Выбираю конкретный селектор */
document.querySelector('.dropbtn').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

Вы выбираете не конкретный селектор, а первый элемент с таким классом. На остальные функционал не распространяется. Но проблема в том, что у Вас и myFunction() выбирает первый элемент .dropdown-content, поэтому даже если Вы поправите логику с .dropbtn, работать всё равно не будет.

Вам нужно сперва сформировать массив всех .dropbtn, потом пройтись по нему, у каждого элемента найти соседний .dropdown-content и уже его открывать/скрывать:

```js
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        let dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content');

        for (let i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            let openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
};

const dropbtn = document.querySelectorAll('.dropbtn');

dropbtn.forEach(function(item){
  item.onclick = function(){
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show')
  };
})
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

body {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Home</button>

  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div>blog</div>
    <div>About</div>
    <div>Contact</div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Home</button>

  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div>blog</div>
    <div>About</div>
    <div>Contact</div>
  </div>
</div>
```